# Is using MBTI and the Jungian functions to create a character a good idea?

Tags: character-development

Whether I am watching, reading, writing or telling a story, I always pay attention to internal coherence in the characters' behaviour (and of course I am not the only one).

By writing and reading, I became able to understand how difficult it is to keep in mind each character's personality and history.

Meanwhile, I learned about MBTI and jungian functions, and although I know MBTI isn't everything, I was thinking of using it in order to structure my characters.

Is it wise, or should I just go with intuition, or should I find another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, why not? I think as long as there is some coherent structure behind the character so that you can establish that this person would behave in thus-and-such a way, and it's consistent and credible, the nature of that structure is up to you. MBTI, Jungian, RPG alignment, personality quizzes — use whatever tool or combination of tools works for you.